# Quickblox: an issue in deleting content item (picture file / blob)

Tags: ios, sdk, quickblox

I am having a weird issue when I try to delete a content item (picture blob item for the user), stored as PNG picture file in the back-end database.

The delete proceeds without errors, but gives "422 Unprocessable Entity". What does this mean? The status of the content item seems to be OK and ready when checked in Quickblox admin panel.

I have uploaded the content with following API call:

```
[QBContent TUploadFile:imageData fileName:@"profile.png" contentType:@"image/png" isPublic:YES delegate:self];
```

I am trying to delete the object with following API call:

```
[QBContent deleteBlobWithID:blobID delegate:self];
```

QB logs:

```
Performing async request: 
DELETE http://api.quickblox.com/blobs/91049.xml
headers:{
    "QB-SDK" = "iOS 1.8";
    "Qb-Token" = b9e3d1cc708c8444070544df8c642ad194509e67;
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
}
parameters:
2013-12-12 14:33:52.328 QBTestApp[21095:6b73] Request finished, response:
headers:{
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 49;
    "Content-Type" = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 12 Dec 2013 13:33:58 GMT";
    "QB-Token-ExpirationDate" = "2013-12-12 15:32:22 UTC";
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
    Server = "nginx/1.0.15";
    Status = "422 Unprocessable Entity";
    "X-Rack-Cache" = "invalidate, pass";
    "X-Request-Id" = 3f235134e5aa0bd012ef78e54cddc164;
    "X-Runtime" = "0.039680";
    "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
}
body:
error:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors/>
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? Thanks (again) in advance! :-)

Comment: Update 14/12/2013: I created a small testsnippet for this and seems that I am able to delete older blob files successfully but not the latest blob file I have created and attached to the user. This brings to my mind whether the **blob item is locked** in case it is attached to some user into _user.blobID_ field? So the correct fix for this problem would be to remove the specific blob linkage from the _user.blobID_ field, then update such user object, and only once this is complete I can remove the blob content file --> to be verified (I will check it on Monday)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feeling that you are trying to delete a blob file that does not exisе. Please make sure that you are trying to delete a blob file after the upload and the creation process is completed(calling completedWithResult: with successful result).

If I could see the order of method calls TUploadFile: and deleteBlobWithID: in the code, I could help you more quickly.

Comment: Thanks @glebus for your feedback. Unfortunately, I have checked the order of the calls and I can assure you that there is plenty of time between the calls. And from the QB dashboard, I can verify that the file exists in the cloud and I can view the image file through the dashboard. I can also download the file programmatically and put the contents of the file into UIImage.. I will double-check this and make a small code snippet to verify this functionality tomorrow.

Comment: About your last update.

I agree - this behavior is not entirely clear. It looks more like a manual memory management in iOS. When you upload a file , you create an object of class content and increase the reference count by 1. If you set blobID of this object to the user.blob_id, it is tantamount to calling retain the object content . During removal of the object content called release method, if it is then its reference count is not 0, an error is returned.

http://quickblox.com/developers/Content#Delete_file

Comment: I think should be added to the documentation that set blobID any to user.blob_id increment the reference count in this blob. And just make a error description, which is returned when you try to delete the blob, more informative.

Comment: Thanks for the reference link @glebus. Yes, this indicates that the reference count being not zero rejects user to delete the content file. I made changes today already but did not have time to verify the change yet, so I will accept this resolution on Monday once completed my verification.

Comment: CONFIRMATION 16/12/2013: The issue is solved. The only way to remove the content file is to remove the references meaning that for this specific issue, I have to set blobID to 0 for the user, then update the user object after I can remove the blob content file. It works now! Thanks @glebus for your consultation!