# Quickblox: Trying to update user and set blobID to zero. Does not update..?

Tags: ios, sdk, quickblox

I have a weird issue happening when trying to set blobID for the existing user zero. This has worked earlier and I do not know what may be causing this.

In relation to item: 
[Quickblox: an issue in deleting content item (picture file / blob)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545222/quickblox-an-issue-in-deleting-content-item-picture-file-blob)

I need to remove blob/content reference from the user in order to remove the user object completely. Now, when trying to set blobID as zero, it does not change but instead updateUsers will return "No data was provided".

So I tried to change also some other data, such as fullName & tags in order to see if any data changes with user object: this query returns sucecss and these other fields have been changed (confirmed with QB admin panel) but blobID is ignored/not changed.

My code:

```
    QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
    user.ID = self.currentUser.ID; // current user QB ID
    user.tags = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"DELETED", nil] mutableCopy];
    user.fullName = @"DELETED";
    user.blobID = 0;
    [QBUsers updateUser:user delegate:self context:contextUpdateProfile];
```

Logs:

```
<Warning>: Performing async request:    
PUT http://api.quickblox.com/users/723606u.xml?user%5Bfull_name%5D=DELETED&user%5Btag_list%5D=DELETED

headers:{
    "QB-SDK" = "iOS 1.8.1";
    "Qb-Token" = 1738d8c1e14a448da4e232ca81d087d1756c6a9b;
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
}

parameters:

{...other_debugs_coming_up...}

<Warning>: -[MyBackend completedWithResult:context:]1659| AA QBUUserResult - contextUpdateProfile: user updated succesfully.
```

What am I doing incorrectly? I am pretty sure this has worked earlier as I have been able to remove users with the same process and have tried to dig into my code if I have changed anything but without success.. :(

Any suggestions/tips are appreciated.

Comment: For deleting Blob Id in user profile, you should pass blobId = -1. But **now** this don't work properly. So you should find another way.. or wait some time for new framework updating.

I try also edit blob and in result I can't. :(

Comment: OK, thanks for quick response @frankWhite. Please let me know once you have done the update of the framework. I'll wait.. :-)

Comment: If I don't forget :) You can also sometime check new version here http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#Framework_changelog:

Comment: :) superb. If you like, please make "for deleting Blob ID in user profile" comment as an answer to this question as it is the correct way to remove the blob ID.. I'll accept that answer as I confirmed my code is now doing it like this. Thanks for the link, I will follow up on it as well.