# Quickblox Delete Blob ID

Tags: ios, sdk, quickblox

I am attempting to delete a blob without success. I read on some SO posts [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545222/quickblox-an-issue-in-deleting-content-item-picture-file-blob) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575360/quickblox-trying-to-update-user-and-set-blobid-to-zero-does-not-update) which mention you need to first set the blob to 0 and then delete the blob. Here is a simple piece of code and it does not work. I always get a 422 error, with NO error message when attempting to delete the blob.

*I also came across the change log from version 1.8.3 which states:*

QBUUser. blobID type changed to NSInteger. Now you can unset blob_id field of user - pass blob_id=-1

*This does not work either*

Any idea? Version 2.1

```
...

NSInteger blobId = self.qbUser.blobID;
self.qbUser.blobID = 0;

[QBRequest updateUser:self.qbUser successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
    if (response.success) { // Always a Success
        [QBRequest deleteBlobWithID:blobId successBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
            // Never Gets Here...
        } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
            // !!! Always Gets Here!!! 422 Error
        }];
    }
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
    // Doesn't Get Here Either...
}];
```

Edit: 
Log of response.error:

```
Error reasons:{
    errors =     {
    };
}
```

Edit 2:
Log of Response:

```
2015-02-26 09:41:33.793 SomeApp[7089:32557338] [QBResponse], status: 422
```

Comment: Please post response.error description

Comment: @IgorKhomenko see edit. There is only a blank error.

Comment: Can you post Xcode logs please, it should be a response

Comment: @IgorKhomenko I posted the response log. Like I said it gives me a 422 error but gives no details. I initially thought it was becuase my blob did not exist. But the blob does exist as I could do a [QBRequest blobWithID]... and it comes back with a blob. I'm at a loss. This appears to be a bug in the framework as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting blob outside the success block.

```
    NSInteger blobId = self.qbUser.blobID;
    self.qbUser.blobID = 0;

    [QBRequest deleteBlobWithID:blobId successBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
        // Never Gets Here...
    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
        // !!! Always Gets Here!!! 422 Error
    }];

    [QBRequest updateUser:self.qbUser successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
         if (response.success) { // Always a Success
         }
    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
         // Doesn't Get Here Either...
    }];
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately this does not work. I still get the same errors. Besides, these calls are asynchronous so they need to be nested.

Comment: You don't need to check response.success because you are already in a success block